# In a multiplayer game developed using client server model with socket.io and node.js how can we describe the osi layers

Tags: multiplayer, websocket

What will the different layers in the stack look like in the osi model?

Answer (score 2):

The [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Comparison_to_other_networking_suites) is mostly a theoretical model. In practice, it tends to break apart as soon as you get below the standardized layers of the Internet protocols (below the transport layer). So this is really more of an academic question.

- HTTP(S) is generally considered an application level protocol, so we are already on the upmost layer of the protocol.
- WebSocket is another application-level protocol on top of HTTP, because each Websocket connection begins with a HTTP request that contains an "upgrade" header. Although some people might disagree and consider it a separate protocol from HTTP because it works very differently from HTTP once the header was sent.
- The netcode protocol of your specific game is yet another application-level protocol on top of Websocket. Which might or might not also have presentation and/or session functionality, depending on what it does in your game.